# Why run a Spring Boot application in a container if always deploying to on-premise VM?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have several Spring Boot applications that I deploy as uber JAR files. They are deployed to a VM running Linux. Given that:

1. All required library dependencies (Tomcat, etc.) are self-contained in the uber JAR.
2. Some applications need to access files on the OS.
3. I have complete control over the Linux machine and OS.
4. All the apps are Spring Boot applications (with some being web applications).
5. I currently run these applications using a process manager, Supervisor.

What benefits are there to running each application in a container such as a Docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The purpose of running applications in a **docker container** is that you can build **docker image** once and run it anywhere: on any cloud, or on any machine.
- If you plan to run your application only in one single on-premise environment, then you might not need to care about docker containers. But as soon as you need to share your application with other people, who would run it on their own machine, then docker containers are your best choice.
- You will never hear "**It works on my machine**" anymore, from people, who share docker images. If it works on your machine, it works anywhere.
- But make sure you move all **environment-specific** parameters to **environment variables**. For example, path to local files on your OS, must be configurable by these **environment variables**, and documented in your **docker image**.
- To summarize: if you run application in docker containers, they will run anywhere, provided user correctly configured **environment variables**.
- In any other cases: for example if you distribute your application as **jar** file, it will not run on a **standalone tomcat server**. You would have to specify "**web.xml**" descriptor and package it as "**war**" file.
- On the other hand, if you distribute your application as a **war** file, it will not run in your **jvm** environment. You would have to change "**pom.xml**" to change the packaging of your application to "**jar**".
- In both of these examples, you have to adapt source code (**pom.xml** or **web.xml**) to run it in correspondent environment.
- So, if I want to run my spring boot application locally, I package it as a "**jar**" file and run it as spring boot application with "**java**" command.
- But when I want to run it on a **standalone tomcat server**, which is installed on **Amazon Cloud EC2** Instance, for example, I would have to change source code **pom.xml** to package it as **war** file, and add "**web.xml**" descriptor.
- With **docker containers** you would never have to make any changes to any source code, to run it anywhere else: all **environment-specific** configuration is exposed as **environment variables**.
- For more details, see "**Store config in the environment**" of **Twelwe-Factor App Manifesto**:
  **https://12factor.net/**
- **Docker containers**, actually, comply with all **12 principles** of **Twelwe-Factor App Manifesto**, so this is another reason to use **docker containers**.